# How to display the name that matches the ID without refreshing/submitting the form in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to display a User's name on top of a box where they enter their Employee # in a form, without having to refresh the page.

For example, they enter their # and then after they click/tab onto the next field, it renders their name on top, which comes from the database, so the user knows they've entered the correct info. This name is stored in a separate model, so I try to retrieve it using the "id/number".

I am not too familiar with AJAX but after reading a few similar questions it seems like an AJAX request would be the most appropriate way to achieve this. I tried to make a function **get_employee_name** that returns the name of the person based on the way I saw another ajax request worked, but I'm not sure how to implement this so it displays after the # is entered.

My page currently loads, but there is never a call to the function/url that searches for the name to display it on the page (because there isn't one). I'm not sure where I might be missing the part that connects these two areas of the code or how to connect these, as I am not too familiar with html and Django, most of this has been trial and error.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,  blank=True)
```

This is the model where the name is stored

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
```

I was reading I can add to the "attrs" in the widget an 'onchange' part, but I am not too familiar with how to approach this and tying it to the ajax request from forms and not the html.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    form = WarehouseForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        # Submission stuff/rules

    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
    })


def get_employee_name(request):
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number')

    try:
        employee = Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number)
    except Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Employee not found'}, status=404)

    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return JsonResponse({'employee_name': employee_name})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('get-employee-name/', views.get_employee_name, name='get_employee_name'),
]
```

The ajax request I tried to create is at the end of this html. I modified a similar request I found, but it does not actually display anything on the screen, not sure if I'm missing an area where the request is actually never being called, as I am not too familiar with how these types of requests work.

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <div>

<!-- Here is where I would want the name to render after the user enters their number and tabs out -->

                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val();
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").data("employee-name");

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:'GET',
            data: {
                'id': employee_number
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
                $('#employee_name').text(employee_name);
            },
            error : function (data) {
                var error_message = data['error'];
                $('#employee_name').text(error_message);
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

How can I call the function from the HTML? Could I do it in such a way that when the user enters 6 numbers it checks? (All employee numbers are 6 digits)

Answer (score 0):

The url has to be the endpoint url which you defined in your `url.py` file

```
<script>
    $("#id_employee_number").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var employee_number = $(this).val();
        var url = $("#warehouseForm").data("employee-name");

        $.ajax({
        url: "/get_employee_name",   // Here 
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            'id': employee_number
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
            $('#employee_name').text(employee_name);
        },
        error : function (data) {
            var error_message = data['error'];
            $('#employee_name').text(error_message);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can append to your GET request a url parameter like: `/get-employee-name/<your employee number here>`
I recommend taking a look at [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) to create url parameters within your django url definitions

I also recommend using underscores **NOT** dashes in your url definitions.

---

So a pseudo working config would be

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('get_employee_name/<int:employeeNum>', views.get_employee_name, name='get_employee_name'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def get_employee_name(request, employeeNum): #You get the employeeNum variable from urls.py
    try:
        employee = Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number)
    except Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Employee not found'}, status=404)

    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return JsonResponse({'employee_name': employee_name})
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
        var employee_number = $(this).val();
        var employeeNum = $("#warehouseForm").data("employee-name");

        $.ajax({
        url: `/get_employee_name/${employeeNum}`,
        type:'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
            $('#employee_name').text(employee_name);
        },
        error : function (data) {
            var error_message = data['error'];
            $('#employee_name').text(error_message);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How would the call would be made from the HTML though? So that it knows when/where to make the call and display the employee_name

Comment: You can have it activate when a button is pressed or you can set the script on an event such as when the DOM is loaded so the request runs as soon as the page is loaded. In terms of button you can make a form that points towards the request and when the user presses the submit button the request will fire.

Comment: Yeah, the reason why I was asking was because I need it to be triggered when the user tabs/clicks out of the field, not upon form submission, since the point of this is giving the user the ability to double check they have entered their ID by checking their name is the one being displayed before they submit the form

Comment: thats another question within itself. Try looking it up on Google, if not then you can come back here and ask.

Comment: The question was how to call the url from the html without refreshing/submitting

Comment: Oh, my fault. In that case you can set the form submission to prevent default from within the function call so `function theRequest(e){e.preventDefault()}` this will prevent your page from submitting. Ive edited the question to show this. In the JS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203485/discussion-between-kevin-hernandez-and-mariana-gomez-kusnecov).